# Best way to "lazy load" multiple short videos

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to figure out the best way to load multiple videos on a page. In my case, these videos will be small autoplaying loops in place of gifs.

Most of the information I could find online suggest "lazy-loading" the videos as needed (when the user scrolls the element into the viewport). This makes sense because it obviously reduces the initial load time, but the only problem is that when a video comes into screen, it will often still be loading.

I also read a solution to this could be to set a buffer distance before it enters the screen, but even then, videos will too often come into screen before they're finished loading. And in all of the examples I've seen of lazy loading, if you scroll bit too fast, multiple videos end up loading at the same time, and finish in no specific order. I may be a bit OCD about my work, but its really bugging me!

I was wondering if it would be an OK idea to just load videos one by one from top-to-bottom as soon as the rest of the page is done loading. This way it wouldn't slow down the initial load, but there would be a much better chance that the next video will be loaded when it enters the screen. is this in any way a worse idea than regular lazy loading?

Comment: go with your idea

Comment: @evgenifotia the only problem with the OP's idea is that, if the user watches the second video first, she'll have to wait for the first video to load first.

Comment: How long do the videos usually take to load?

Comment: The videos usually don't take very long to load. But since they autoplay, I want them loaded as soon as possible so that they are already playing when the user sees them. I can't just fetch them when the user clicks a play button like a regular video.